# Query about getting GPS Location

Tags: blackberry, gps

Is there any way to set Criteria for LocationProvider depending upon the network provider, means determining whether the network provider supports CellSite mode or autonomous mode or any other mode.

How to define criteria for GPS fix when you have so many network provider in front of you?

Thanx.